# How to Use Laser Data

Tags: ros, laser, hokuyo-node, hokuyo, hokuyo-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use laser data in my program(I want C++ code)
,
I can see ranges data of laser scanner with   `#rostopic echo /scan/ranges` but how can i use it in my codes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137941/how-to-use-laser-data/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "ranges" member of a [LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) message is represented by a `std::vector<float>` and can be used just like any other std::vector of floats.

It might help to have a look at the laser callbacks in [slam_gmapping](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/hydro-devel/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L476), [AMCL](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L816) and [hector_mapping](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/master/hector_mapping/src/HectorMappingRos.cpp#L229). For the latter, an example of accessing range data is the [rosLaserScanToDataContainer](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/master/hector_mapping/src/HectorMappingRos.cpp#L229) function.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-03-10**:
Thanks Dear Stefan for your time...
I want to read for example ranges[50], I do it by bellow code but it caused error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
"sensor_msgs:: LaserScan scan;
std::cout<<scan.ranges[20]<<std::endl;"
What's my problem?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-03-10**:
You instantiate a empty LaserScan message and try to access element 50 of the ranges vector, which does not exist.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-03-10**:
What i must to do Stefan to read for example ranges[20] ?? when i use "rostopic echo /scan/ranges" it print a lots of ranges, i think it was more than 200s...

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-03-10**:
Sorry to be blunt, but you will have to do some basic studying of C++ and the C++ ROS API. The code piece you posted just creates a empty message and tries to access (the non-existing) 20th or 50th range of it. You have to actually subscribe to the topic and use a callback to get the data coming in on a topic. See http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B) to get a basic understanding of how subscribing to topics works.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-03-10**:
Thanks Dear Stefan, I had not read that tutorial...
I'm was Stupid... sorry for my silly question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would subscribe to the LaserScan message at `/scan` and then do what you want to do with it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-03-10**:
Thanks Dornhege for your response, i want to use some data on scan/ranges for example: ranges[1], ranges[40],ranges[100],... to process them.
How can i do that?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-10**:
Basically exactly like you've written here. Check out Stefan's answer for more detail.